# Brother MFC-7420 Scanner on Ubuntu 12.04: Invalid Argument

Tags: 12.04, scanner, brother, sane, xsane

I have a Brother MFC-7420, which also works as a scanner. I have attached this machine to a computer running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit via USB.

I installed the following package:

```
brscan2-0.2.4-0.i386.deb
```

Now when I start `xsane`, the device is detected. However, when I try to scan or run a preview scan, I get the message `Could not start scanner: Invalid Argument`. The same problem exists if I run `xsane` as root, so I don't think it's a privilege problem.

There's no output on the console while running `xsane` (see screenshot below). The dialog box showing the error appeared just after pressing the "scan" button in `xsane`.
[image: Sreenshot showing the error]

What can I do to get this scanner running?

Comment: `xsane` appears to be invoking `sane` with bad syntax. To be sure, can you post a screenshot showing the error? If that is what's happening, it should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), probably in `xsane`. ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) In addition to a screenshot, please run `xsane` in a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and give all the text in the Terminal; please also specify what messages appeared when. Please **edit your question** to provide all this info.

Comment: I've added the information you requested.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it by editing `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`.

I uncommented the line:

```
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", OWNER="root", GROUP="root"
```

Then edited it to be:

```
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", OWNER="root", GROUP="saned"
```

After that I added my user to the `saned` group. It all works now.

The problem is that it wants to run as root till you do this.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above work, what worked for me was to go to the brother site. The issue is that - at least with Brscan2 x64 - that the drivers are installed to the wrong directory. go to [Brother sacanner Faq](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00101) if you look @ the section: that says

> I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 or higher. I cannot scan from my Brother
>   Machine.

the instructions say to copy some files - that was what ultimately solved it for me. I expected that when I installed the Brother linux drivers, that was it. But no, the drivers installed to directories that my version of ubuntu (linux mint Nadia Xfce x64) doesn't use. So copying those files over immediately solved it.

Comment: didn't work for me, I had to  emulate android and use the android app instead.