# Brother WLAN Scanner DCP-7055W not working ("invalid argument")

Tags: 12.04, scanner, sane

I'm having trouble getting the scanner of my Brother DCP-7055W working over WLAN. I've already installed the official drivers from Brother, and the printer itself is working fine.

I've set up the scanner to use a static IP address (192.168.002.150). Using Brother's `brsaneconfig4` I've added the scanner as follows (using `002` instead of `2` following [this tip](http://neithere.net/2013/02/18/archlinux_brother_7860.html)):

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=DCP-7055W model=DCP-7055W ip=192.168.002.150
```

Pinging the scanner works fine:

```
$ brsaneconfig4 -p
test DCP-7055W
ping 192.168.002.150 -w 10

PING 192.168.002.150 (192.168.2.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.150: icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=9.21 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.150: icmp_req=2 ttl=255 time=5.67 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.150: icmp_req=3 ttl=255 time=6.01 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.150: icmp_req=4 ttl=255 time=3.33 ms
```

I've also made sure that [the issue with 64bit drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00101) is fixed:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35 Sep 25 07:18 /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so -> /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     39 Sep 25 07:18 /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1 -> /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 129376 Sep 25 07:18 /usr/lib/sane/libsane-brother4.so.1.0.7
```

I've also fixed the UDEV rules according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/260343/31948):

```
$ grep saned /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules 
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", OWNER="root", GROUP="saned"
```

However, I cannot actually scan: Whatever tool I try, I get the following error:

```
$ scanimage -T
scanimage: open of device brother4:net1;dev0 failed: Invalid argument
```

This happens both as normal user and when using `sudo`, so it shouldn't be a permission problem.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1:** Now with some more verbose debug output:

```
# SANE_DEBUG_BROTHER4=255 scanimage
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of brother4 to 255.
[brother4] brother init
[brother4] brother version: 1000001
[brother4] starting bus scan
[brother4] scanning bus 005
[brother4] found dev 0483/2016
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 004
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 003
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 002
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 001
[brother4] found dev 18A5/0302
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0002
scanimage: open of device brother4:net1;dev0 failed: Invalid argument
```

**UPDATE 2:** I now also tried using the scanner via USB. I get the same error ("Invalid argument"), but at a later point in the scanning process:

```
# SANE_DEBUG_BROTHER4=255 scanimage -T
[sanei_debug] Setting debug level of brother4 to 255.
[brother4] brother init
[brother4] brother version: 1000001
[brother4] starting bus scan
[brother4] scanning bus 005
[brother4] found dev 0483/2016
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 004
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 003
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 002
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0001
[brother4] scanning bus 001
[brother4] found dev 04F9/02CE
[brother4] found dev 1D6B/0002
scanimage: rounded value of br-x from 215.9 to 215.88
scanimage: rounded value of br-y from 355.6 to 355.567
scanimage: sane_start: Invalid argument
[brother4] cancel called...
```

A [Brother scanner FAQ](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/Public_s/id/linux/en/faq_scn.html#f00106) mentions that this could be due to the scanning area being to small, but passing `-x 100 -y 100` to `scanimage` doesn't change anything. I also tried to explicitly pass all other arguments that `scanimage -h` returned for the scanner, but without success.

Installing `libsane-extras`, as [suggested here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/24946/comments/24) did not change anything.

Following the [troubleshooting of a similar problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/24946), I've run

```
# strace -o strace.out -f scanimage -T
```

At the end of the output, there's the following:

```
4019  ioctl(151, USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB or USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB32, 0xbfbfe0a8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
4019  gettimeofday({1387487538, 170759}, NULL) = 0
4019  ioctl(151, USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB or USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB32, 0xbfbfe0a8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
4019  gettimeofday({1387487538, 170926}, {4294967236, 0}) = 0
4019  gettimeofday({1387487538, 171013}, {4294967236, 0}) = 0
4019  gettimeofday({1387487538, 171104}, NULL) = 0
4019  ioctl(151, USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB or USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB32, 0xbfbfe068) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
4019  write(2, "scanimage: sane_start: Invalid a"..., 40) = 40
4019  ioctl(151, USBDEVFS_CONTROL or USBDEVFS_CONTROL32, 0xbfbfe2e0) = 5
4019  ioctl(151, USBDEVFS_RELEASEINTERFACE, 0xbfbfe304) = 0
4019  semop(1245186, {{0, 1, SEM_UNDO}}, 1) = 0
4019  semctl(1245186, 0, IPC_64|IPC_RMID, 0xbfbfe2b8) = 0
4019  close(151)                        = 0
4019  munmap(0xb755a000, 134532)        = 0
4019  munmap(0xb7525000, 104424)        = 0
4019  munmap(0xb751b000, 38084)         = 0
4019  munmap(0xb74ef000, 176256)        = 0
4019  exit_group(4)                     = ?
```

The whole log is full of `ioctl` calls referring to `USBDEFVS_SUBMITURB` and getting a `No such file or directory`. However I don't know enough about the Linux USB internals to make sense of that.

**UPDATE 3:** My kernel:

```
# uname -r
3.2.0-57-generic-pae
```

Relevant output from `dmesg`:

```
[10210.399432] usb 1-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'scanimage' sets config #1
[10210.399446] usb 1-1: usbfs: process 5347 (scanimage) did not claim interface 1 before use
[10211.428906] usb 1-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'scanimage' sets config #1
[10213.519554] usb 1-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'scanimage' sets config #1
[10213.519567] usb 1-1: usbfs: process 5352 (scanimage) did not claim interface 1 before use
[10214.549025] usb 1-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'scanimage' sets config #1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the link below;

- [For Brother hardware](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sane#For_Brother_hardware)

Problem :

```
-name=Scanner---adding type brother
-name=SCANNER_DCP770CW
```

My Brother type MFC-J430W.

Answer (score 0):

It Seems that the Brother driver .deb package installs the sane driver in the wrong directory for Ubuntu 16.04.
Try the following:

1. Copy all files from */usr/lib64* to */usr/lib*

   `sudo cp /usr/lib64/* /usr/lib`
2. Copy all files from */usr/lib64/sane* to */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane* or */usr/lib/sane*

   `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/* /usr/lib/sane`

   `sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane`